Nextjs Link always replacing route instead of appending
I am facing issue with nextjs Link component. It is always replacing the url path with whatever is given in href field. For example: I have this folder structure for app routing:
   -> profile  
             -> page.tsx
             -> layout.tsx
             -> locations (folder)
                         -> page.tsx

Now, when I use Link inside page.tsx of profile folder to append /locations in the url. it instead replaces /profile with /locations.
what I expect
/profile -> /profile/locations  (append)
what is actually happening
/profile -> /locations (replace)
I saw the documentation, according to which, the behavior which I am expecting should be happening by default without changing anything in replace prop.
But even I set replace either true or false, I does not affect anything.
